# Advantages/Disadvantages of webView versus 3rd party library for handling HTML text

Tags: ios, uiwebview

**Context**

Working to build a quiz app that consumes questions and multiple choice answers from an API that may have HTML tags in them, that need to be honored.We may be able to limit the number of different HTML tags.

**Question**

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a `UIWebView` to display this text content versus using a 3rd party library such as: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText  to convert the HTML styles into attributed strings.

**My List**

**`UIWebView` Pros**

- Pretty much plug and play
- Not relying on 3rd party library with unknown support roadmap

**`UIWebView` Cons**

- May be hard to get text to look the same as native text
- Formatting the frame of the webview is harder
- May give API creator excuse to not be as strict in scrubbing their
  data
- Cannot select text to copy/paste or define
- Does not work well within small areas such as table cells
- Often a slight delay, even when loading text from disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other webview cons:

1. Delay associated with loading and rendering the content
2. Can't use in smaller areas well (like table view cells)

`DTCoreText` generally offers you a lot more flexible options and should work well for your described situation.

Comment: Would you still consider there being a delay if the data was downloaded to local disk before being loaded by the UIWebView?

Comment: It's worth testing yourself, but I have previously always observed some delay even when only loading a couple of small paragraphs from disk.